# How to remove that digit/non character which is at farthest distance from remaining characters in binary image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to remove that digit/non character which is at farthest distance from remaining characters in binary image. All the renaming characters and digits have fixed distance. Like in this image:

[image: Image1]

I want to remove "5" and in this image:

[image: Image2]

I want to remove non-characters.

I want this only when image have 2 rows (like Image1 and Image2). In a single row image I don't want to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't quite figure out what Mark was doing, so I decided to create my own method.  If you have the Statistics Toolbox, I'd apply a [`kmeans`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) clustering to all of the centroids of the characters and remove the centroid that has the least amount of characters - namely the isolated island with 1 character.

Given your first image, I had to do some pre-processing to remove the green bounding box that surrounded each character.  When I read in the image from StackOverflow, you had an associated colour map to it and was read in as an indexed image.  I had to convert the indexed image into a colour image, then I extracted out the green channel so that the light green bounding box was removed.

```
[X,map] = imread('http://s17.postimg.org/5quw8e6m7/plate2.png');
out = ind2rgb(X,map);
im = out(:,:,2);
```

I now invert the image and get the centroids of each character.  Inverting is required because object pixels are white in MATLAB, but they are black in your image.  I'll also get the bounding boxes as you'll need this for later when you want to remove the single character:

```
im_invert = ~im;
s = regionprops(im_invert, 'Centroid', 'BoundingBox');
centroids = reshape([s.Centroid], 2, []).';
```

You should be aware of [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html), because you used that in one of your previous posts.  We simply measure blob properties for each detected blob in the image.  A blob in our case is a character.  Now, apply a `k`-means clustering on the centroids.  I have to extract out the centroid for each character, so I unpack all of the centroids in the `regionprops` structure into a comma-separated list and reshape the array so that each row is a centroid and each column is a dimension.  The first column is the `x`/column coordinate the second column is the `y`/row coordinate.

Given your images, I'm going to assume 3 centroids - one of them consists of the first row of characters, another one consists of the second row of characters, and the last one only has the isolated one.  I'm going to run this a few times to be sure that I get the right centroids, then we'll look at which centroid only contains 1 member and remove it:

```
[idx,c] = kmeans(centroids, 3, 'Replicates', 10);
```

`idx` consists of the cluster membership ID that a particular centroid belongs to and `c` is the representative centroid that collects all of the characters that belong to a cluster together.

When I run `kmeans`, this is what I get:

```
>> idx

idx =

     3
     1
     3
     1
     3
     1
     3
     2

>> c

c =

  178.7152   74.3279
  310.7455   67.1364
  191.5493  149.3756
```

OK, so it looks like cluster #2 has the isolated centroid.  All of the other ones get assigned to either cluster #1 or cluster #3.  We need to figure out which cluster has the single centroid, and you can do this by just tallying up how many characters belong to each cluster and isolating out the one that has a single member.  You can use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) or [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) for that:

```
cnts = histc(idx, 1:3);
cnt_one = find(cnts == 1);
one_idx = find(idx == cnt_one);
```

We first count up how many characters belonged to each cluster, then determine which of the cluster IDs only has a single member.  That's stored in `cnt_one`.  Once we find this cluster ID, we figure out which character is the isolated cluster.  `one_idx` contains the detected index of the isolated character.  As such, we're going to use this character's `'BoundingBox`' property to set the region to white so you can remove the character:

```
s_remove = floor(s(one_idx).BoundingBox);
im(s_remove(2):s_remove(2)+s_remove(4), s_remove(1):s_remove(1)+s_remove(3)) = 1;
```

`s_remove` contains the bounding box information of the isolated character.  This is a 4 element array where the first two elements are the `x`/column coordinate and `y`/row coordinate of the top-left corner of the bounding box, and the third and fourth element is the width and height of the bounding box respectively.  I need to take the `floor` because this can potentially have floating point values and if you want to index into your image, you need to remove the decimal places.

Removing the decimal places, I set the bounding box spanned by the above information to all 1s, removing the character from the image.

Showing this new image gives us:

```
imshow(im);
```

[image]

---

Let's repeat this for the second image.  There's no colour map associated with this, so you can use a straight up `imread`:

```
im = imread('http://s10.postimg.org/4ww3bjia1/plate.png');
im_invert = ~im;
```

You can then use the same code that I wrote above and we get:

[image]

---

To fully reproduce what I have, here's the code that you can easily copy and paste into MATLAB and run it:

```
%// Image #1
[X,map] = imread('http://s17.postimg.org/5quw8e6m7/plate2.png');
out = ind2rgb(X,map);
im = out(:,:,2);

%// Image #2
%im = imread('http://s10.postimg.org/4ww3bjia1/plate.png');

%// Invert the image, then find the centroids of each character and bounding boxes
im_invert = ~im;
s = regionprops(im_invert, 'Centroid', 'BoundingBox');
centroids = reshape([s.Centroid], 2, []).'; %'

%// Find the clustering memberships of each character
[idx,c] = kmeans(centroids, 3, 'Replicates', 10);

%// Count up how many characters belonged to each cluster
cnts = histc(idx, 1:3);

%// Figure out which cluster ID gave us 1 cluster
cnt_one = find(cnts == 1);

%// Find the character that gave us the 1 cluster
one_idx = find(idx == cnt_one);

%// Access that character's BoundingBox property 
s_remove = floor(s(one_idx).BoundingBox);

%// Fill in the image at that bounding box location with white to remove it
im(s_remove(2):s_remove(2)+s_remove(4), s_remove(1):s_remove(1)+s_remove(3)) = 1;

%// Show the image
imshow(im);
```

Comment: Hello again. What to do if we have more than 3 centroids in an image. Like if we have another extra character in above image how to remove extra isolated character? K-mean clustering approach works well for if we have only one isolated character. but gives error if we have more than one isolated character.

Comment: @Nomi - One thing I can suggest is to run `kmeans` with 3 clusters, then 4 clusters... up to as many as you need it to be... say... 10 clusters.  Then, find the OCR results for each, then determine which of those results gives you something meaningful.  Use whichever amount of clusters gave you the most meaningful result.  A simple alphabetic check may be use... something like making sure the first three characters are letters and the last are numbers... for each cluster result you make.

Comment: I used 5 clusters for an image and got `idx = 5
     1
     5
     1
     4
     3
     4
     2`

Comment: I used 5 clusters for an image and keep `cnts=histc(idx,1:3)` same .got `idx = 5    1     5     1     4     3    4   2` and `cnts = 2 1 1`. but an error on `one_idx = find(idx == cnt_one); ` `Matrix dimensions must agree.`

Comment: I know why I got error but not understand how to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you could do it quite easily without Matlab, just using ImageMagick which is installed on most Linux distros and available for free on OS X and Windows.

First, squidge the image up left-right into a column a single pixel wide - I will do it 20 pixels wide at the right so you can see it as thick black bars on the right.

```
convert 1.png \( +clone -resize 1x! -resize 20x! -threshold 99% \) +append result1.png
```

[image]

If I do the same thing again, but just a single pixel wide and convert it to text this time, you will easily see the black and the white blocks - and that there are 2 rows:

```
convert 1.png -resize 1x! -threshold 99% txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,236,255,srgb
0,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,1: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,2: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,3: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,4: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,5: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,6: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,7: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,8: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,9: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,10: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,11: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,12: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,13: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,14: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,15: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,16: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,17: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,18: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,19: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,20: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,21: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,22: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,23: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,24: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,25: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,26: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,27: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,28: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,29: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,30: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,31: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,32: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,33: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,34: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,35: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,36: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,37: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,38: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,39: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,40: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,41: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,42: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,43: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,44: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,45: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,46: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,47: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,48: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,49: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,50: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,51: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,52: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,53: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,54: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,55: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,56: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,57: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,58: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,59: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,60: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,61: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,62: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,63: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,64: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,65: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,66: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,67: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,68: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,69: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,70: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,71: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,72: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,73: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,74: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,75: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,76: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,77: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,78: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,79: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,80: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,81: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,82: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,83: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,84: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,85: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,86: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,87: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,88: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,89: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,90: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,91: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,92: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,93: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,94: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,95: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,96: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,97: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,98: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,99: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,100: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,101: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,102: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,103: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,104: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,105: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,106: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,107: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,108: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,109: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,110: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,111: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,112: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,113: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,114: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,115: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,116: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,117: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,118: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,119: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,120: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,121: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,122: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,123: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,124: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,125: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,126: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,127: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,128: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,129: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,130: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,131: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,132: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,133: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,134: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,135: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,136: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,137: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,138: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,139: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,140: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,141: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,142: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,143: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,144: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,145: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,146: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,147: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,148: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,149: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,150: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,151: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,152: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,153: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,154: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,155: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,156: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,157: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,158: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,159: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,160: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,161: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,162: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,163: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,164: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,165: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,166: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,167: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,168: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,169: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,170: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,171: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,172: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,173: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,174: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,175: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,176: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,177: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,178: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,179: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,180: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,181: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,182: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,183: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,184: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,185: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,186: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,187: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,188: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,189: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,190: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,191: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,192: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,193: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,194: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,195: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,196: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,197: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,198: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,199: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,200: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,201: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,202: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,203: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,204: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,205: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,206: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,207: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,208: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,209: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,210: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,211: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,212: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,213: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,214: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,215: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,216: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,217: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,218: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,219: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,220: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,221: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,222: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,223: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,224: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,225: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,226: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,227: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,228: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,229: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,230: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,231: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,232: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,233: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,234: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,235: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
```

If I now squidge the rows down flat to a single row, but for illustration, make it 20 pixels tall:

```
convert 1.png \( +clone -resize x1! -resize x20! -threshold 99% \) -append result2.png
```

[image]

You can see there are two blocks, the rightmost one being the one you want to remove. If I do the same in text format, you can get the coordinates of where the `5` starts:

```
convert 1.png -resize x1! -threshold 99% txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 414,1,255,srgb
0,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
1,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
2,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
3,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
4,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
5,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
6,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
7,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
8,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
9,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
10,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
11,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
12,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
13,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
14,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
15,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
16,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
17,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
18,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
19,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
20,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
21,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
22,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
23,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
24,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
25,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
26,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
27,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
28,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
29,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
30,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
31,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
32,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
33,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
34,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
35,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
36,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
37,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
38,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
39,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
40,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
41,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
42,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
43,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
44,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
45,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
46,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
47,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
48,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
49,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
50,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
51,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
52,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
53,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
54,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
55,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
56,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
57,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
58,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
59,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
60,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
61,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
62,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
63,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
64,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
65,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
66,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
67,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
68,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
69,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
70,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
71,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
72,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
73,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
74,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
75,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
76,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
77,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
78,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
79,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
80,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
81,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
82,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
83,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
84,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
85,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
86,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
87,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
88,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
89,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
90,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
91,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
92,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
93,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
94,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
95,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
96,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
97,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
98,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
99,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
100,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
101,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
102,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
103,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
104,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
105,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
106,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
107,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
108,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
109,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
110,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
111,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
112,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
113,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
114,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
115,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
116,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
117,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
118,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
119,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
120,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
121,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
122,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
123,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
124,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
125,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
126,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
127,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
128,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
129,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
130,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
131,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
132,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
133,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
134,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
135,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
136,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
137,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
138,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
139,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
140,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
141,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
142,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
143,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
144,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
145,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
146,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
147,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
148,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
149,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
150,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
151,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
152,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
153,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
154,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
155,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
156,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
157,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
158,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
159,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
160,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
161,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
162,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
163,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
164,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
165,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
166,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
167,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
168,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
169,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
170,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
171,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
172,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
173,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
174,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
175,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
176,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
177,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
178,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
179,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
180,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
181,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
182,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
183,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
184,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
185,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
186,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
187,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
188,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
189,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
190,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
191,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
192,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
193,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
194,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
195,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
196,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
197,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
198,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
199,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
200,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
201,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
202,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
203,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
204,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
205,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
206,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
207,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
208,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
209,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
210,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
211,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
212,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
213,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
214,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
215,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
216,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
217,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
218,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
219,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
220,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
221,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
222,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
223,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
224,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
225,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
226,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
227,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
228,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
229,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
230,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
231,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
232,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
233,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
234,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
235,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
236,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
237,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
238,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
239,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
240,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
241,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
242,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
243,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
244,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
245,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
246,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
247,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
248,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
249,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
250,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
251,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
252,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
253,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
254,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
255,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
256,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
257,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
258,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
259,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
260,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
261,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
262,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
263,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
264,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
265,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
266,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
267,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
268,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
269,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
270,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
271,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
272,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
273,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
274,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
275,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
276,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
277,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
278,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
279,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
280,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
281,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
282,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
283,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
284,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
285,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
286,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
287,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
288,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
289,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
290,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
291,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
292,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
293,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
294,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
295,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
296,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
297,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
298,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
299,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
300,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
301,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
302,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
303,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
304,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
305,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
306,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
307,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
308,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
309,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
310,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
311,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
312,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
313,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
314,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
315,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
316,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
317,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
318,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
319,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
320,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
321,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
322,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
323,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
324,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
325,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
326,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
327,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
328,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
329,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
330,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
331,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
332,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
333,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
334,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
335,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
336,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
337,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
338,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
339,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
340,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
341,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
342,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
343,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
344,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
345,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
346,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
347,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
348,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
349,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
350,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
351,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
352,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
353,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
354,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
355,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
356,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
357,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
358,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
359,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
360,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
361,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
362,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
363,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
364,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
365,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
366,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
367,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
368,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
369,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
370,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
371,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
372,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
373,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
374,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
375,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
376,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
377,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
378,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
379,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
380,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
381,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
382,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
383,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
384,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
385,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
386,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
387,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
388,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
389,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
390,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
391,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
392,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
393,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
394,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
395,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
396,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
397,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
398,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
399,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
400,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
401,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
402,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
403,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
404,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
405,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
406,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
407,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
408,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
409,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
410,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
411,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
412,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
413,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
```

So, I can now take those coordinates and draw a white rectangle over the `5` in your image, except you wouldn't be able to see that, so I'll do it in red instead:

```
convert 1.png -fill red -draw "rectangle 299,38 320,102" result.png
```

[image]

Comment: @Mark Setchell. Good approach but I have to do it on matlab. I can't use any other software.

Comment: Is there any way to convert into matlab program?

Comment: I don't know Matlab, but all I am doing is resizing the image so it is 1 pixel wide in the first case and till it is 1 pixel tall in the second. I then look through that column, or row, of pixels till I find the transtion from white to black, i.e. from 255 to 0, or 1.0 to 0.0 depending how your data are scalled. Maybe convert to greyscale as first step so you don't need to look at RGB values. That must be pretty simple in Matlab.

Comment: A quick look at Matlab documentation suggests `imresize()` is your friend.

Comment: `imresize` resize the whole image into 1 pixel wide or 1 pixel tall.

Comment: @Mark Setchell. Appreciate your response and your approach. Thanks.

Comment: @rayryeng.  Can you give me the Matlab algorithm for this approach.

Comment: @Nomi - Yup I can.  It wouldn't be fair if you accepted my answer though because Mark Setchell came up with the approach.  However, if that's what you really want, I can write something up.

Comment: @rayryeng. Very positive thinking. Nice.

Comment: @rayryeng. But I am stuck at this point. I am trying hard but can't succeeded yet. That's y ask for your help. Hope you understand.

Comment: @rayryeng It's fine, thanks. Go for it and have the points- I'll learn something too :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell - Cheers Mr. Setchell :) I'll write something up during my lunch break.  Currently working ATM.

Comment: @rayryeng. Kindly post the answer.

Comment: @Nomi - I will soon.  I'm just figuring out how I'd do this in MATLAB

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah, come on Ray ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell - Couldn't quite figure out how you did it with your method, so I went with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer only in a general sense on how to tackle the problem. I'll (have to) assume that
a) all your images look similar like the ones you linked and
b) that the characters are continuous sets of black pixels on the white background
c) that the lines are sufficiently distinct so that complete lines of white pixels separate them

1) Decide whether the image has two rows or only one. Go through the image from the top and decide whether there are one or two lines of characters. If the last line contained black pixels and the current one doesn't, the previous line ended. From the first character line do remember the first pixel line in the image and the last which contains the pixels.

2) Do the same thing now in columns on the image area which contains the first character line. Go backwards from right to left. The first completely white column after the first set of columns which contain black pixels is your last character. Remember these columns.

3) Now you have the exact area which contains the last character in the first line.

Your question is not clear whether you always want to remove it (then simply set all those pixels in that rectangle to white) or whether it could possibly also an acceptable character which you want to keep. In that case it's a challenging problem, depending on how variable the acceptable characters appear: do a OCR (character recognition or comparison with given examples) on that and decide whether the character is one you want to blank or not. Maybe you can provide examples of each acceptable character and compare the correlation between the example and the image rectangle and decide upon using a threshold

Comment: I have 2 types of images. First is single line images and second is double line images. Single lines images are working well. But in case of double line images sometimes I got extra digit/character on right side (Which I don't want). And there is also a possibility to get nothing extra on right side. Extra character/digit i got is always far from remaining characters. therefore I want to use distance between characters. It measure the distance among characters and skip that character which has maximum distance than remaining of characters.